# Typescript error when default clause of switch for an unkown union type

Tags: typescript

I'm reading data from a file, which may have more data in it than my code cares about. I have a typescript type for each object type I want to process. But in the case of some unsupported object type, I want do something with that object.

The problem is that typescript thinks I have exhausted all possibilities and that my default clause is impossible to get to.

```
// Untyped example data source.
function loadFromSomeFile(): any {
  return [{ objType: "A", a: 1 }, { objType: "B", b: 2 }] as any
}

// Union type of supported data from data source.
type A = { objType: "A", a: number }
type B = { objType: "B", b: number }
type ObjTypes = A | B

// Load the data.
const arr: ObjTypes[] = loadFromSomeFile()

// Switch on the type of each object. 
for (const obj of arr) {
  switch (obj.objType) {
    case "A":
      console.log('A', obj.a)
      break
    case "B":
      console.log('B', obj.b)
      break
    default:
      // Fall though case for unsupported objType
      console.log('unkown objType: ' + obj.objType)
      // ^ TS Error: objType does not exist on type 'never'
  }
}
```

[Error on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Untyped%20data%20source%0D%0Afunction%20loadFromSomeFile()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22A%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22B%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5D%20as%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Union%20type%20of%20supported%20data%20from%20data%20source.%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22B%22%2C%20b%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20ObjTypes%20%3D%20A%20%7C%20B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Load%20the%20data.%0D%0Aconst%20arr%3A%20ObjTypes%5B%5D%20%3D%20loadFromSomeFile()%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Switch%20on%20the%20type%20of%20each%20object.%20%0D%0Afor%20(const%20obj%20of%20arr)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20switch%20(obj.objType)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20%22A%22%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('A'%2C%20obj.a)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20%22B%22%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('B'%2C%20obj.b)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0D%0A%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Fall%20though%20case%20for%20unsupported%20objType%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('unkown%20objType%3A%20'%20%2B%20obj.objType)%20%2F%2F%20objType%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'never'%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

I thought of trying to add a third option to the union like:

```
type X = { objType: string } // unknown
type ObjTypes = A | B | X
```

But now when `obj.objType === 'A'` typescript can't tell if it's an `A` or an `X` since it's a valid type for both.

How can I tell typescript that there may also be unknown and unhandled values, and that my list is not exhaustive?

Comment: type Other = { objType: any }
type ObjTypes = A | B | Other

Comment: @DanielA.White Well, that silences this error, but it appears TS is not actually inferring the proper type, because if I try to access a property on known types, that now errors. I've updated the code in the question to cover this case.

Comment: The best I can come up with is `type ObjTypes = A | B | {objType?: never}`, but it requires `strictNullChecks`, and it infers `undefined` type for `obj.objType` in the default clause - no idea how to declare types so that it will be `string` there without affecting other branches, short of type assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wrestling with this for a while, I decided to give the unknown types a concrete type with a fixed value, that is incorrect.

```
type A = { objType: "A", a: number }
type B = { objType: "B", b: number }
type Unknown = { objType: '___unknown-obj-type___' }
type ObjTypes = A | B | Unknown
```

This causes the default clause of the switch fallthrough to this type. And I can still access the objects properties at runtime for real values.

It feels a bit like a hack but this has the least amount of code readability compromises so far, IMHO.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Untyped%20data%20source%0D%0Afunction%20loadFromSomeFile()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22A%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22B%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5D%20as%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Union%20type%20of%20supported%20data%20from%20data%20source.%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22B%22%2C%20b%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Unknown%20%3D%20%7B%20objType%3A%20'___unknown-obj-type___'%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20ObjTypes%20%3D%20A%20%7C%20B%20%7C%20Unknown%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Load%20the%20data.%0D%0Aconst%20arr%3A%20ObjTypes%5B%5D%20%3D%20loadFromSomeFile()%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Switch%20on%20the%20type%20of%20each%20object.%20%0D%0Afor%20(const%20obj%20of%20arr)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20switch%20(obj.objType)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20%22A%22%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('A'%2C%20obj.a)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20%22B%22%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('B'%2C%20obj.b)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0D%0A%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Fall%20though%20case%20for%20unsupported%20objType%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('unkown%20objType%3A%20'%20%2B%20obj.objType)%20%2F%2F%20objType%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'never'%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
return [
    { objType: "A", a: 1 }, 
    { objType: "B", b: 2 },
    { objType: "C" }
    { foo: "bar" }
] as any
```

as the data, and setting the type to be:

```
type ObjTypes = A | B | any
```

Then, inside each of your `case` blocks, cast the object to the type expected, either `A` or `B`, etc.

```
case "A":
  let a = <A>obj;
  console.log('A', a.a)
  //console.log('A', a.x) // TS error! 
  break
```

logs to the console:

```
A 1
B 2
unknown objType: C
unknown objType: undefined
```

See updated [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Untyped%20data%20source%0D%0Afunction%20loadFromSomeFile()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20a%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22B%22%2C%20b%3A%202%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22C%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%22bar%22%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%5D%20as%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Union%20type%20of%20supported%20data%20from%20data%20source.%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22B%22%2C%20b%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20ObjTypes%20%3D%20A%20%7C%20B%20%7C%20any%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Load%20the%20data.%0D%0Aconst%20arr%3A%20ObjTypes%5B%5D%20%3D%20loadFromSomeFile()%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Switch%20on%20the%20type%20of%20each%20object.%20%0D%0Afor%20(const%20obj%20of%20arr)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20switch%20(obj.objType)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20%22A%22%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20%3CA%3Eobj%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('A'%2C%20a.a)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('A'%2C%20a.x)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20%22B%22%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('B'%2C%20obj.b)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0D%0A%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Fall%20though%20case%20for%20unsupported%20objType%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('unkown%20objType%3A%20'%20%2B%20obj.objType)%20%2F%2F%20objType%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'never'%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Union with `any` allows accessing any property on any kind of the object, without any checks at compile time

Comment: Well, inside of the `case "A":` block, you can cast the object as type `A`. will update answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can get not only A or B from the file, don't declare the type as A | B.

See the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Untyped%20data%20source%0D%0Afunction%20loadFromSomeFile()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20a%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22B%22%2C%20b%3A%202%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22C%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%22bar%22%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%5D%20as%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Union%20type%20of%20supported%20data%20from%20data%20source.%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20objType%3A%20%22B%22%2C%20b%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Load%20the%20data.%0D%0Aconst%20arr%20%3D%20loadFromSomeFile()%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Switch%20on%20the%20type%20of%20each%20object.%20%0D%0Afor%20(const%20obj%20of%20arr)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20switch%20(obj.objType)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20%22A%22%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20%3CA%3Eobj%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('A'%2C%20a.a)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20%22B%22%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('B'%2C%20obj.b)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0D%0A%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Fall%20though%20case%20for%20unsupported%20objType%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('unkown%20objType%3A%20'%20%2B%20obj.objType)%20%2F%2F%20objType%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'never'%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)